# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spring"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile, cloud9

After running `bundle install --without production` on cloud 9 this is the error that I am getting:

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spring":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    spring (= 2.0.1)

  In Gemfile:
    spring

    spring-watcher-listen (= 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      spring (~> 1.2)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Your gem version of 'spring-watch-listen' is at 2.0.0. This is stopping you from being able to bundle your gem libraries because of dependency issues. Try changing the version directive in your Gemfile. Simply remove the number after the comma.

```
 #/path/to/project/Gemfile
 gem 'spring-watch-listen', '2.0.0'
```

After saving the file run this command from your linux terminal in the root directory of your application.

```
  bundle install
```

If that does not work you can try running the following from the root directory of your application.

```
 bundle update
```